# Adding multiple Drawable views to a Layout element

Tags: android, android-layout

I've defined a custom drawable shown below:

```
private class SquareDrawableView extends View {
    private ShapeDrawable mDrawable;

    public SquareDrawableView(int x, int y, int size, int color, Context context) {
        super(context);

        mDrawable = new ShapeDrawable(new RectShape());
        mDrawable.getPaint().setColor(color);
        mDrawable.setBounds(x, y, x + size, y + size);
    }

    public void setColor(int color) {
        mDrawable.getPaint().setColor(color);
    }

    protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
        mDrawable.draw(canvas);
    }
}
```

I'm trying to tile a number of these across a LinearLayout.  Presently, when I run this code, I just get one square appearing in the "first" position of the LinearLayout. What am I doing wrong here?

```
top = (LinearLayout)findViewById(R.id.top);
SquareDrawableView[] topSquares = new SquareDrawableView[horizCount];

for(int i = 0; i < horizCount; ++i) {
    topSquares[i] = new SquareDrawableView(i*SQUARE_SIZE,0,SQUARE_SIZE,BLUE,this);

    top.addView(topSquares[i]); 
}
```

Comment: @pskink "I'm trying to tile a number of these across a LinearLayout. Presently, when I run this code, I just get one square appearing in the "first" position of the LinearLayout." ?

Comment: Please check if the value of horizCount is 1.

Comment: Also ensure that if orientation of parent linear layout "top" is vertical then you have set its height as "wrap content". If not only one element will be visible as per height of parent linear layout and others will be truncated. However if the linear layout is horizontal then you need to ensure that you are setting its width as wrap content and keeping the linear layout in a ScrollView.